# Custom path for active_model_serializer serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

By default, the gem [active_model_serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable) (from rubygems, the version 0.8.1) looks for the serializers in `app/serializers`.

However, I have a `shared` directory at the root of Rails project sharing models, serializers, specs with other projects as a git subtree.

How to specify to active_model_serializer to looks for files in `app/serializers` and `shared/serializers` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do ... simply by loading the path `shared/serializers` in my `application.rb` by this way:

```
module MyRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
   ...
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('shared/serializers').to_s
  end
end
```